# When I use <ui:inputEmail I get one thing. When I use <input type="email" I get another

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

If I use this code for my input box to take an email address:

```
<input type="email" onkeyup="{!c.sendSearchKeyChange}"/>
```

The event sent to sendSearchKeyChange has a prototype of KeyboardEvent.  And, most important to me, I can say event.target.value, and find out the value of the input box.

If I code the input box like this:

```
<ui:inputEmail keyup="{!c.sendSearchKeyChange}"/>
```

The event sent to sendSearchKeyChange has a prototype of just plain Object.  And event.target.value is undefined.

I thought the keyup attribute supported by  just went straight through to the same place the onkeyup attribute goes to on the regular html element, but I guess not.  Is the event that is sent documented somewhere?

---

(After getting an answer suggesting how to code it.)
Actually, when I define a data attribute like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="thePhoneNumber" type="String"/>
```

And set up my input element like this:

```
<ui:inputPhone aura:id="phone" label="phone" placeholder="123-456-7890" 
               value="{!v.thePhoneNumber}" keyup="{!c.sendPhoneKeyChange}"/>
```

And have my controller like this:

```
sendPhoneKeyChange: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var target = event.getSource();
    var theValue = target.get('v.value');
    console.log('theValue', theValue);
    theValue = target.get('v.thePhoneNumber');
    console.log('theValue', theValue);
    var myEvent = $A.get('e.c:PhoneKeyChange');
    myEvent.setParams({searchKey: theValue});
    myEvent.fire();
},
```

I get an undefined for theValue, whether I use v.value or v.thePhoneNumber.  I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform what you are trying to do, you just have to make these modifications to your code:

```
<ui:inputEmail keyup="{!c.sendSearchKeyChange}" updateOn="keyup"/>

({
    sendSearchKeyChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var email = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    }
})
```

some reference here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputText.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_client_side_controller.htm

Comment: Yeah.  That will work.  I need to focus less on how the object is defined, and more on how to do the task I need to do.

Comment: Hmm.  When I went to do it, I couldn't make it work.  I've expanded my question, above.

Comment: Remember to change your ui:inputEmail  to updateOn="keyup", the default is on change (when you do onblur). If you don't change this property the v.value of the input won't be updated when you do keyup.
    
    Change this <ui:inputPhone aura:id="phone" label="phone" placeholder="123-456-7890" 
               value="{!v.thePhoneNumber}" keyup="{!c.sendPhoneKeyChange}"/> to this <ui:inputPhone aura:id="phone" label="phone" placeholder="123-456-7890" 
               value="{!v.thePhoneNumber}" keyup="{!c.sendPhoneKeyChange}" updateOn="keyup"/>

Comment: That works!  My html - javascript skills won't transfer directly, it seems.  I'll have to treat writing code in Aura as a new problem.  Thanks for the help.